# How can I set up a UIGestureRecognizer on a UIImageView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uigesturerecognizer

How can I add a UIGestureRecognizer to recognise left or right swipes on top of a UIImageView? I just need an action to be called when the swipe is left and another action for when the swipe is right.

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: I have looked at various tutorials across the internet but none of them work for me. The main one I've been looking at is: http://www.icodeblog.com/2010/10/14/working-with-uigesturerecognizers/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create 2 swipe gestures and add them to your image view.

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer * recognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(myRightAction)];
    [recognizer setDirection:(UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight)];
    [myImageView addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
    [recognizer release];

UISwipeGestureRecognizer * recognizer2 = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(myLeftAction)];
    [recognizer2 setDirection:(UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft)];
    [myImageView addGestureRecognizer:recognizer2];
    [recognizer2 release];
```

Comment: I've done this, however the swipes are only being recognised about one out of twenty five times. Why is this?

Comment: make sure you are swiping horizontally, and not diagonally (a much higher start point with a much lower end point). this swipe gesture is picky. I saw the same thing when I first added mine.

Comment: I am swiping as straight and horizontal as I can, still isn't working. And it's about one in fifty actually...

Comment: if on the main thread.. is your main thread tied up somewhere?

Comment: What do you mean? How can I check this? :)

Comment: I mean, if you are doing processing of somesort, like downloading something? when you are trying to swipe... and you are downloading something on your main thread, your swipe will not be recognized until that process is complete.

Comment: I don't think any process is happening. Nothing is appearing on my NSLog either...

Answer (score 2):

Have you set

```
@property(nonatomic, getter=isUserInteractionEnabled) BOOL userInteractionEnabled
```

to true before you attach the `UIGestureRecognizer`?

If not try that

If that doesn't work, you could add a temp view and add the gesture recognizer to the temp view and then add the imageview to the temp view